# Supercomputers around the world, which allow access for researchers outside the country

Tags: high-performance-computing

In a [previous question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/supercomputers-around-the-world) it has been shown the computation capabilities of the countries all over the world. However, if I didn't miss something, the use of such supercomputers is limited to researchers within the country. Is there any supercomputer that can be used for foreign researchers?

Comment: +1. Some systems in USA, such as the DOE-funded ones, have a "Director's Discretion" award, which allows the Director to allocate a small time (1 million CPU hours) to anyone s/he wants to give it to, if the proposal is very good. The researcher can't be working with anyone from Iran, Iraq, Syria, Yemen, Sudan, or Somalia on the project though. It has become harder & harder over the years though. HPC centers are extremely expensive to build/maintain (not just hardware/energy but also 100s of salaries for workers), only governments can afford it. If you're not paying tax, you don't get access.

Answer (score 10):

### PRACE (Partnership for Advanced Computing in Europe)

[PRACE](https://prace-ri.eu) is a European organization managing 7 main HPC centers in France, Germany, Italy, Spain, and Switzerland, and with 26 member countries that provide some additional resources.

Access is through the evaluation of research proposals via peer-review, and some calls specifically mention that they are "designed for projects requiring access to resources not currently available in the PI’s own country and whose projects do not require resources on the very largest (Tier-0) European Supercomputers or very large computational allocations".

Comment: @Nike Dattani you are right. I've took a brief look at their website and only members from European countries are allowed.